# Name For Stack With Unique Values

Tags: c#, .net, data-structures

I'm using `.NET 3.5` to create an application that requires a `Stack<T>` with unique values. I realize I could call `Contains()` before every `Push()`, but it makes sense semantically that I roll my own "unique stack" (`UniqueStack<T>` or maybe `HashStack<T>`?). I'm having a hard time to determine a strong name for this data structure.

I hate the fact that `Stack<T>` doesn't implement some `IStack<T>`...

Thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: I'd go with UniqueStack<T> - seems nice and clear what it does.

Comment: The odds that this question will ever be useful to anybody else are very low.

Comment: @Hans - That's a rather absurd comment. There are completely valid reasons for having a stack that only maintains unique values. Just because my question "isn't useful to everybody" doesn't mean it's not a valid question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- ExclusiveStack?
- DistinctStack?

Personally, I like your UniqueStack or UniqueItemStack

Comment: I'll accept this as answer since I will go with `UniqueStack<T>`.